# Fallo en array con bucles

Tags: javascript

Después de probar varias cosas, creo que esto es lo que más puede acercarse a como es, el ejercicio, lo que me pide finalmente es que "la variable **`numeros`** debe contener números del 0 al 8". (ESTE ES EL FALLO QUE ME DA, QUE NO SE CUMPLE ESA VARIABLE)

```
// Crea una variable llamada números que sea un "array" vacío

let numeros = [];
console.log(numeros);

// Crea un bucle for que recorra los números empezando en 0 y llegando 
// hasta 10 (INCLUYENDO EL 10). En cada iteración, empuja ese número i 
// dentro del array numeros

for ( var i=0; i =< 10; i= ++) {
    numeros += i;
}
console.log(numeros[i])          

// Para terminar, vamos a quitar los dos últimos números del "array".

numeros.splice(9, 2); // esto tengo dudas si seria (8, 2). 
console.log(numeros);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cuál es el problema en cuestión. Mencionaste un fallo: ¿cuál fallo?

Comment: 1. En JS no existe el operador lógico `=<`, en su lugar debe ser `<=`. 2. En vez de `i= ++` tiene que ser `i++`. 3. `numeros` es un array, por lo que `numeros += i;` es incorrecto, no puedes *incrementar* un array de esa forma, en su lugar, debe ser `numeros.push(i);`. 4. `numeros.splice(9, 2);` lleva 2 parámetros: `9` es la posición del elemento desde donde va a partir para remover del array, y `2` es la cantidad de elementos que se eliminarán a partir de la posición `9`, eliminando el elemento `9` y `10`, así que sería lo correcto. [Demo](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/abQroQG).

Comment: No edites la pregunta con la respuesta. Cuál sería el sentido de responder una pregunta ya respondida sino?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes muchos errores, dejo el código corregido y comentado.

```js
let numeros = []; 
console.log(numeros);


//preferir usar let i=0 por sobre var i=0
//                         v--- Es i++ (no i=++)
for ( let i=0; i <= 10; i++) {
// Es "<=" (no =<), siempre el menor o mayor primero, luego el igual
// 

  // numeros += i; //NO, esto es para concatenar o sumar, no para agregar a un array
  numeros.push(i);
}
//console.log(numeros[i]) // error, "i" no existe aqui
//console.log(numeros) 
  

numeros.splice(9, 2); 
console.log(numeros);
```

Con respecto a tu pregunta es `splice(9,2)`

Tu tienes 11 elementos, cuyos índices irían desde el `0` hasta el `10`. Tu quieres borrar los 2 últimos es decir los índices `9` y `10`, por tanto el primer argumento de la función [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) indica el índice de inicio (es decir el 9) y se borrarán 2 elementos (el segundo argumento)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!! Acabo de corregir los fallos que me dices (vaya tela poniendo =<... ), pero sigue sin darme el ejercicio por correcto. Respecto a push, no me había quedado claro que debía usarlo en este ejercicio, pero si que entiendo que no debe ser "numeros +=1"  A ver si doy con la tecla :(

Comment: Hola @Carmen, como es que no da el ejercicio O_O ??? el resultado final debería ser 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ??? o algo me estoy perdiendo?

Comment: Si!! El resultado final debe ser ese, pero me sigue dando error :(

Comment: A ver, muéstrame una foto de lo que tienes

Comment: vale!! el fallo era que era splice!! muchas gracias!!!